# Does not returning false in ruby equate to a !variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails project I have the following method defined in a module:

```
  def self.create_response_backup
    response_backup = ResponseBackup.new(location_name: site.site_name, response_data: response_json)

    if !response_backup
      return response_backup.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end

    return response_backup
  end
```

My question is:

If I do, `if create_response_backup ... else ... end` should this method return anything but true - would it know to skip to the else part? or, because it returns a value other then false, would it continue in the top part of the if statement?

in other words should I do: `if create_response_backup == true ... else ... end`

Comment: It is not clear why you are mentioning "return anything but true".

Comment: In rails `if create_response_backup` should evaluate either true or false by default and you do not need to explicitly check for true or false.

Comment: i may be wrong, but it seems to me that you need ResponseBackup.create rather than ResponseBackup.new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362 gives a good overview of truthy and falsy values in Ruby.  Relative to your code above,

```
return response_backup.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

would result in a non-nil string being returned, which would in turn evaluate to truthy.

If you had an if statement:

```
if create_response_backup
    puts "A"
else
    puts "B"
end
```

I would expect your code above to only, ever, output `A` (except in the case where something in response_backup.errors.full_messages.to_sentence evaluted to nil and raised a nil value error)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `if create_response_backup` will always evaluate to true, unless `response_backup.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` is ever `nil` or `false`

Ruby evaluates objects as `true` in an `if` condition. Your method will always either return a `ResponseBackup` object or the value or `response_backup.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` (which I will assume is a String).

If you want to verify that the backup got created, you could do

```
if create_response_backup.class == ResponseBackup ... else ... end
```

Depending on the broader scope of this method, you'll need to decide whether it's better to use a check against the return value or refactor the method to return true or false.